# Why maps with different CRS still overlaps with each other

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

My country has the standard CRS using EPSG:3826, while some of the open data uses EPSG:4326 as default. I understand the differences between projections and fully aware that unexpected errors might occurs when doing spatial join between different CRS layers.

Since they are not even using the same projection, why would GIS (I'm using QGIS for instance) still map them onto the same window **most of the time**? And **sometimes** different CRS layers just won't show in the same location.

Comment: It's called *project on the fly*, if there is a coordinate transformation available then QGIS projects the data to match the CRS of the canvas. The ones that don't show up aren't defined properly or the coordinate transformation isn't known.

Comment: Documented in https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html?

Comment: Wow that is exactly the explanation I need, thank you!